# How to prevent the results from being truncated?

Tags: 7, search

I want to remove the limit of character imposed from Drupal 7 on the search result page. That is, displaying my result in full rather than truncating the results and adding ... at the beginning and end of the result. I already have a search-results.tpl.php in my templates and looks like that:

```
<?php if ($search_results): ?>
<?php print $search_totals.' << '.str_replace('%20',' ',basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])).'>>';?>
  <ol class="search-results test <?php print $module; ?>-results">
    <?php print $search_results; ?>
  </ol>
  <?php print $pager; ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Your search yielded no results');?></h2>
  <?php print search_help('search#noresults', drupal_help_arg()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I prevent the results from being truncated?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a new view mode for search results:

1. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/page/display` (where "page" is your content type)
2. Expand the `Show Custom display settings` fieldset
3. Check `Search index`

[image: Search index view mode]

4. Click Save
5. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/page/display/search_index` (again, where "page" is your content type)

My advice would be to use download the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module (and enable the Display Suite module and Display Suite UI module) for extra fields and more options. No custom theming or coding required!

Comment: Ok i have installed ds module...now what should i do?

Comment: Just follow the steps as described in my answer, you should be fine.